# safe enable_shared_from_this usage

Tags: c++, boost

Please consider the following simplified example:

```
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
#include "boost/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.hpp"

using namespace boost;

class State : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<State>
{
public:
    shared_ptr<State> GetSelf()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    };
    // returns following state
    virtual shared_ptr<State> Execute() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
shared_ptr<T> Create()
{
    return shared_ptr<T>(new T);
}

class MyState2;

class MyState1 : public State
{
    virtual shared_ptr<State> Execute()
    {
            if (change of state)
          return Create<MyState2>();
            else
              return GetSelf();
    };
};

class MyState2 : public State
{
    virtual shared_ptr<State> Execute()
    {
            if (change of state)
          return Create<MyState1>();
            else
              return GetSelf();
    }; 
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    shared_ptr<State> pCurrentState = Create<MyState1>();  // <-- OK
//  State* pCurrentState(new MyState1);                    // <-- Runtime error
    while (...)
      pCurrentState = pCurrentState->Execute();

    return 0;
}
```

The State-class is part of a 'framework'. It is the base for user defined states in a lightweight state machine, where each state returns its follower state. In case the state does not change, it returns itself. The framework user may arbitrarily derrive from class State. Obviously it is not allowed to create 'uncontrolled' instances of derrived classes (would result in runtime error if GetSelf() is invoked). To point the user to the right direction, a Create() function template is provided to create 'controlled' instances. Since I want to make usage as foolproof as possible, how can I make sure a user won't create any instances of derrived states which are not under shared_ptr control? Or at least give a meaningful error message (at compile time?) if he does so.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that you really want to use inheritance for this kind of customization? Perhaps some kind of containment relationship would be better; in general, that works better for things that are so intimately tied to `shared_ptr` that they need `enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: Really weird. The default constructor for `boost::enable_shared_from_this` just creates an empty `weak_ptr` object.

Comment: If all instances are managed by shared pointers, why do you need `GetSelf()` at all? Its only use is to get a shared pointer from an *unmanaged* pointer/reference, which you say shouldn't be allowed. You only need `shared_from_this()` at all if you need to get a shared pointer from within a member function for some reason.

Comment: Well I'm not sure, but how can a containment relationship help? Could you be more concrete?

Comment: Sorry, comment refers to Nicol Bolas

Comment: Maybe I stripped the example a little bit too much, I'll add some more detail to make it clear ...

Comment: @raines It is good enough. Just remove `Create` and `GetSelf` functions to make it smaller.

Comment: @raines: "how can a containment relationship help?" If the "derived" class isn't actually derived but just stores a `Base` object as a member, then you can force it to create them via a factory method. And therefore, you can force them to use a `shared_ptr`. So is there a specific _need_ for the class to be derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to prevent unmanaged instances is to make the constructor of each derived class private. Your factory function will need to be either a friend or a member of the class it's creating; if you want to keep your factory template, then it will need to be declared *before* the derived classes in order to make it a friend:

```
template<typename T>
shared_ptr<T> Create()
{
    return shared_ptr<T>(new T);
}

class Derrived : public Base
{
private:
    friend shared_ptr<Derrived> Create<Derrived>();
    Derrived() {}
    // Client implementation goes here
};
```

However, I would usually recommend that you don't force a class to be managed in a particular way. You should only do something like this if the classes themselves *require* that they are managed by shared pointers in order to function correctly (that is, they need to call `shared_from_this()` from their member functions for some reason). Otherwise, just organise your framework so that it uses shared pointers, and anyone using the framework will have to do likewise with no need for strange enforcement mechanisms. There should be no need for `GetSelf()` at all, since you'll always have a shared pointer available to copy if you have access to an object at all, and no need for `enable_shared_from_this` unless the classes need to access shared pointers internally (which is rather an unusual thing to do).

UPDATE: In your use case, I don't think it's possible for the base class to enforce the use of shared pointers (but please correct me if I'm wrong). It might make sense to enforce the use of shared pointers when calling the functions that require them. You'll be able to create unmanaged objects, but not do anything dangerous with them.

```
class State : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<State>
{
public:
    // returns following state
    friend shared_ptr<State> Execute(shared_ptr<State> state) {
        return state->Execute();
    }
private:
    virtual shared_ptr<State> Execute() = 0;
};

class MyState : public State
{
    shared_ptr<State> Execute() {return shared_from_this();}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    shared_ptr<State> state1(new MyState);  // <-- OK
    State * state2(new MyState);            // <-- OK, but can't be used
    Execute(state1);                        // <-- OK
    // Execute(state2);                     // <-- Error
    // state2->Execute();                   // <-- Error
}
```

Comment: If the constructor of `Base` is private, I'm fairly sure you can't derive from it, since you would have to call the constructor.

Comment: @Nicol: Correct, the constructor of `Base` can't be private. As I said, "make the constructor of each derived class private".

Comment: I think the point of enforcing it is so that, if a class relies on `shared_from_this`, you will be unable to create that class without putting it in a `shared_ptr`. A good API is easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly.

Comment: I thought of this too: make the base class constructor protected, but you cannot ensure that the constructor of the derrived class is protected too and therefore it is still possible to create uncontrolled instances of it.

Comment: please consider edited example, I hope my intention is clearer now.

Comment: Sounds good, but shouldn't the public Execute() function be static? Ohterwise it has to be invoked like: pCurrentState=pCurrentState->Execute(pCurrentState), or am I misstaken? And what is the friend modifier good for?

Comment: @raines: `friend` makes it a non-member function, with access to the protected and private members, in the same namespace as the class, so you call it as `Execute(state)`. You could make it static if you prefer, and call it as `State::Execute(state)`.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for enlightening me :-) I think I'll go with your solution, since it matches best with the existing design.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, and of course thanks to all other contributors!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do what you want in the *general* case.

If `Base` isn't a base class (ie: they're not supposed to derive from it), then it's easy. Make your constructor(s) factory function(s) and make the constructor(s) private. Therefore, they have to go through your factories, and therefore you can ensure that they used `shared_ptr` to wrap them.

However, if you are allowing the user to derive classes from them, then all bets are off. So you need to think about two things:

1. Do I *really* need `enable_shared_from_this` here?
2. Do I *really* need to allow inheritance?

1: The code you posted does not really give a reason why you *need* to use `enable_shared_from_this` at all. The only place you use it is in a function that returns a `shared_ptr` to that instance. Well, who is it returning it to? The user of that object. Who can only create an instance... by *having* a `shared_ptr`.

In short: you give them something that they necessarily already have access to. The function is useless.

Well, it's useless unless you are violating proper use of `shared_ptr`. In general, once you wrap a pointer in a `shared_ptr`, you either keep it that way or make a `weak_ptr` out of it. You almost *never* give someone a naked pointer to that object. And if you do, then it should be a clear sign that they are **not** to store that pointer or expect to maintain any form of ownership of it in any way, shape, or form.

Therefore, them being able to get a `shared_ptr` from a naked pointer is bad design.

`enable_shared_from_this` is intended for the *single* use of naked pointers to `shared_ptr` held objects that you cannot avoid: `this`. It exists because a member function might need to call an external function with a pointer to that object, but that external function takes a `shared_ptr` or a `weak_ptr` instead of a naked pointer. It is not meant to be a way to allow bad design.

2: You're building a state machine. So why does the base class `State` need to be derived from `enable_shared_from_this`? If a derived class's `Execute` method is going to return itself, that's up to that derived class to deal with it. It should not be the responsibility of the base class to provide that. And it *certainly* should not be provided by a public function.

In short, each derived class needs to inherit from `enable_shared_from_this` if it wants to return a pointer to itself. It therefore becomes the *user's* responsibility to keep these things straight, not yours.

Comment: @raines: I added an explanation for how to deal with that.

Comment: The idea is that the state machine is driven by an instance which simply cyclically calls pCurrentState.Execute() and makes the result state to ist current state, no matter what the current state actually is. And I don't want each derrived state to implement GetSelf().